# Why sh.calculate does not calculate the formulas in worksheet "sh"?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

**This is what I want:** User enters formulas in different cells. At this point nothing should be calculated. Then she/he runs the macro which calculates all formulas in those cells and the results are shown in those cells.

**So**: I set the calculation to manual. And defined my macro to call : sh.calculate. Where *sh* is the worksheet the user will be using.

Issue: even after running the macro those cells still show the formula and not the result of it. i.e. if a cell is: **=2+2** ,after running the macro it still shows **=2+2** instead of **4**.

This is how I set it to manual calculation when the excel file is opened:

```
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

After user adds formulas to different cells in UserForm sheet, he/she runs this macro:

```
sub calcFormulas()
    dim sh as Worksheet
    Set sh= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserForm")
    sh.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: show more of your code, especially the dimming and setting of `sh`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent i am sure that is not where the problem is. But I added the code in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell format is "Text", formulas entered are not executed but treated as plain text. Change the cell format to e.g. "Standard" and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

Did have you added below syntax in your code ?

```
Range("B5").Formula = "=2+2"
```

instead of something like

```
Range("B5") = "=2+2"
```

As said, code of your sh file will be really very helpful.

Comment: No I am not adding any formula! The user is adding formulas and we want to calculate it.

Comment: Ok so you can basically instead of using the Range("B5") = "Your user defined formula", use Range("B5").Formula = "Your user defined formula"